# WHERE IN clause in temporary columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that creates two temporary columns. Is there a way to check if column 2 value exists in column 1 value?

```
select x as column1, y as column 2
```

Result:

```
column 1   |  column 2
x            y
w            x
```

how do I check if x exists in column 1 ? Ultimately I only want to get all the values in column 2 that do not have a matching value in column 1, Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- I think it would be helpful if you gave us a look at some sample rows and columns, and included an example of how you want the result to look, as well.

Comment: So you don't have a table. Just a `select` of literal values?

Comment: `select y from t where not exists (select x from t u where u.x = t.y)`?

Comment: What is a "temporary column"? Temporary objects do exist, but columns aren't one of them. Do you mean you have values that are inserted into columns in a temporary table?

Comment: `select * from ( select x as column1, y as column2 from yourtable) as t where column1 = value`

Comment: Sorry guys - it's my first time posting question here.

What I meant to say is, I created 2 columns based on a condition from other columns and gave them aliases.. so they are like temporary columns..? not sure what else to call it.

from my example above I need to compare the values in these two "temporary" columns and get the unique values of column 2. as you could see "x" appeared in both columns. I need to eliminate it from column 2

how can i go through column 1 and check the values if they match with column 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXCEPT for this:

```
Declare @testTable Table (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));
 Insert Into @testTable (col1, col2)
 Values ('x', 'y')
      , ('w', 'x');

 Select col2 From @testTable tt
 Except
 Select col1 From @testTable tt;
```